# "Nautilus restart required" by Dropbox

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, dropbox

I've just installed on my new pc Ubuntu 14.04, and one of the first programs I installed is Dropbox. But everytime I turn on my pc, it ask me to restart Nautilus because of Dropbox. If I restart Nautilus, it happens again.

Comment: Dunno, is it happening only after startup, or even if you restart Dropbox? Have tried reinstalling Dropbox? Does the integration (sync) actually work? This usually happens after Dropbox update or some major change, but that's probably not the case, but it still means that DB has a feeling something changed.. everytime you restart computer/DB.

Comment: Did you use the button or did you use some other way to restart nautilus? Please use the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First try `sudo nautilus -q`. If this did not work, log off and log on.

Comment: I get the following error do you know why?  `(nautilus:2493): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 2.10.0

** (nautilus:2493): CRITICAL **: Another desktop manager in use; desktop window won't be created

(nautilus:2493): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed`